# Legendre Differential equation, n(n-1) or n(n+1)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

I am confused regarding the Legendre Differential Equations' coefficients.
In some books its,

$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+n(n-1)y=0$

and somewhere it is,

$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+n(n+1)y=0$

what is its correct form?

Comment: Perhaps both forms are correct.

Comment: There is just a shift of the index. The second one is simpler (two less characters to be typed).

Comment: Oh, i got it, thanks, n -> n-1